# Bash Array not accepting WildCard

Tags: linux, bash, networking, centos, redhat

I have an Array that I have setup in a bash script. My goal is to ping through a particular port on a a server with many network interfaces. For example the ping -I eth3 172.26.0.1 command to force ping through eth3

When I setup a bash Array I can get code to work if I call the Elements (ports) individually. For example here I tell it to ping Element 2 or eth5

```
ethernet[0]='eth3'
ethernet[1]='eth4'
ethernet[2]='eth5'
ethernet[3]='eth6'

ping -c 1 -I ${ethernet[2]} 172.26.0.1
```

The script works and pings through eth2

```
[13:49:35] shock:/dumps # bash -x ARRAY
+ ethernet[0]=eth3
+ ethernet[1]=eth4
+ ethernet[2]=eth5
+ ethernet[3]=eth6
+ ping -c 1 -I eth5 172.26.0.1
PING 172.26.0.1 (172.26.0.1) from 172.26.0.192 eth5: 56(84) bytes of data.
From 172.26.0.192 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 172.26.0.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3001ms
```

However if I use a wildcard instead of just element 2 it dies on the second element (Eth4)

```
ethernet[0]='eth3'
ethernet[1]='eth4'
ethernet[2]='eth5'
ethernet[3]='eth6'


ping -c 1 -I ${ethernet[*]} 172.26.0.1

[13:48:12] shock:/dumps # bash -x ARRAY
+ ethernet[0]=eth3
+ ethernet[1]=eth4
+ ethernet[2]=eth5
+ ethernet[3]=eth6
+ ping -c 1 -I eth3 eth4 eth5 eth6 172.26.0.1
ping: unknown host eth4
```

Any thoughts, as to why the wildcard is dying on the second element in the Array? I am new to scripting, I am really just trying to use what I have learned from this article and apply it to a useful networking script. Thanks

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-array-tutorial/

EDIT - I am not sure why I got voted down on this this question. Please Advise

Comment: The ping command that you are creating is wrong.  You need to issue a separate ping command for each interface.

Comment: `${ethernet[*]}` expands to all array elements as you see `eth3 eth4 eth5 eth6`. Use `for` loop to get around this `for i in  ${ethernet[*]}; do ping -c 1 -I $i 172.26.0.1; done`

Comment: @NarūnasK Quote variable expansions. Especially array expansions with `[@]` to keep them safe for values with spaces.

Comment: If any tutorial is telling you to use `${name[*]}` with no quotes to expand an array, I suggest throwing it in the trash immediately. See BashFAQ #5 -- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005 -- and its links for an introduction to arrays with a focus on best practices.

Comment: BTW -- if `ping -c 1 -I eth3 eth4 eth5 eth6 172.26.0.1` fails the same way, when you run it on your command line typed just that way (no arrays involved), why do you think the issue has anything to do with shell arrays, vs with the command-line syntax for `ping`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-I` option only takes one interface; you need to loop over the array:

```
for ifc in "${ethernet[@]}"; do
    ping -c 1 -I "$ifc" 172.26.0.1
done
```

Comment: I would not have guessed the ping arguments where the cause of my pain! The For Loop worked thanks!

Answer (score 3):

With xargs:

```
printf "%s\n" "${ethernet[@]}" | xargs -I {} ping -c 1 -I {} 172.26.0.1
```

Comment: Why not `%s\0` and `xargs -0`? If you're going to do a thing, might as well do it right. :)